# Region of ellipse and greens theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Let γ be the ellipse $x^2 + 4y^
2 = 4$, oriented anticlockwise. Compute $\int_c(4y − 3x)dx + (x − 4y)dy$

I used green theorem with P and Q. and got $$-3\int\int_\ dxdy$$

The answer is $-6\pi,$ so how do I get $2\pi$ from the double integral? Or am I just tackling the problem all wrong?

Comment: green is Green: always use a Capital for names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double integral will give you the area of the ellipse.

Your ellipse is
$$\left( \frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{1}\right)^2 =1 $$ with $a=2$ and $b=1$ and has area $\pi a b= 2 \pi$

Comment: what would the bounds be though? isn't 2pi usually expressed in term of d(theta) not dx or dy?

Comment: dx dy is a 2d cartesian area element, and the double integral is over the entire ellipse so it is calculating the area of the ellipse. You don't need to change to another coordinate system.

Comment: denominator should be 4 right not 2?

Comment: A pleasure. You can see the details of the double integral, in both cartesian and polar coordinates, here http://mymathforum.com/calculus/29970-area-ellipse.html

Comment: Regarding denominator, 2^2 = 4.